# Debugging large text files taking too much time

Tags: c++

I created a data bag structure. I read the text of a file and convert to lexicographical order. In order to do this I have to convert two string to lower case to compare them(One for the current node and one for the node that is next to it). But my problem is when I have big text files, it has to keep converting the string to lower case for each node I insert and sometimes it takes a long time to process. I was wondering if there are any ways better ways of adjusting this so I can increase the performance time.

```
void insert(string v)
{
if(head == NULL){ //empty list

        head = new BagNode;
        head->dataValue = v;
        //head->dataCount = 0;
        head->next = NULL;

}
else
{
        BagNode * n = new BagNode;      // new node
        n->dataValue = v;
        BagNode * current = head;           //for traversal
        //current = head;
        n->dataCount = 0;
            if(!isBefore(current->dataValue, v))        //new head
            {
                n->next = head;
                head = n;
            }
            else{           //mid and tail insert
                while(current->next && isBefore(current->next->dataValue,v))
                {
                    current = current->next;
                }
                n->next = current->next;
                current->next = n;

            }   
     }      
}
```

Compare Two Nodes

```
bool isBefore(string a, string b) 
{
  transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), ::tolower);
  transform(b.begin(), b.end(), b.begin(), ::tolower);
    if(a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you use a linked list? That will get you O(horrible) performance when the list gets big, if you keep iterating over the whole list for each new entry.

Comment: I find your title confusing. What is taking too long, running the program on big files or actually debugging it?

Comment: To start I would save `datavalue` as a lowercase string.  That way you would only lowercase the thing once.

Comment: @Robert debugging large text files.

Comment: @Matt so would I just create another node for it?

Comment: @Thompson no, just do the transformation before the line `...datavalue = v;`

Comment: You know what, that may be why its taking too much time. I'm having to transform each node every time I insert

Comment: @Matt so in my isBefore method, I wouldn't need to use the transform then I assume.

Comment: @Thompson right, once in the empty case, and once in the new node case.  None in the `isBefore`.

Comment: @Matt once I make the comparison, would I be able to output the string in the current form it was in.

Comment: @Matt it worked! its taking only about 2 seconds compared to 30 seconds debugging the same file I had. Thank thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the repeated calls to `transform` like this:

```
void insert(string v)
{
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.end(), ::tolower);
if(head == NULL){ //empty list

        head = new BagNode;
        head->dataValue = v;
        //head->dataCount = 0;
        head->next = NULL;

}
else
{
        BagNode * n = new BagNode;      // new node
        n->dataValue = v;
        BagNode * current = head;           //for traversal
        //current = head;
        n->dataCount = 0;
            if(!isBefore(current->dataValue, v))        //new head
            {
                n->next = head;
                head = n;
            }
            else{           //mid and tail insert
                while(current->next && isBefore(current->next->dataValue,v))
                    {
                        current = current->next;
                    }
                    n->next = current->next;
                    current->next = n;

                }   
         }      
    }

bool isBefore(string a, string b) 
{
    if(a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

You can see some addition information on transform [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).  This suggestions that transform is loop over your range.  A way to find something like this would be compile with `-pg` flags on GCC.  This will enable profiling and you would see a hotspots with the functions `isBefore` and `transform`.